# Seeking advice on sharing Netty boss/worker pools

Tags: netty

Context: Netty 3.6.3.Final, Java 1.7, Scala 2.9.x

In order to minimize the number (of possibly idling) threads, I'd like to share NIO client/server and worker pools with different NIO socket channel factories (TCP) and one NioDatagramChannelFactory. I'm using at least two (or three with the Finagle stack) sets of server/client bootstraps, each with their own NIO socket channel factories. Using a new cached thread pool for each and every boss and worker pool result in a load of threads which are not used most of the time. The rough goal would be to limit the number of workers over all bootstraps/channel factories to 2 * CPU core count and number of bosses to CPU core count.

I'm trying to switch over to NioServer/ClientBossPool and NioWorkerPool for one of my own set of bootstraps. But depending of the configuration of the underlying ThreadPoolExecutor, shutting down a bootstrap causes the main thread to wait forever on a AbstractNioSelector shutdown latch.

```scala
class NioClientBossPoolTest {

  @Test def shutdown() {
    val corePoolSize = 1
    val maxPoolSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    val keepAliveSeconds = 60
    val keepAliveUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS

    val blocking = true
    val queue: BlockingQueue[Runnable] =
      if(blocking) new LinkedBlockingQueue[Runnable](Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      else new SynchronousQueue[Runnable]()

    val executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize,
        maxPoolSize,
        keepAliveSeconds,
        keepAliveUnit,
        queue)

    val clientBossPool = new NioClientBossPool(executor, 1) // B
    new NioServerBossPool(executor, 1) // C
    val workerPool = new NioWorkerPool(executor, 1) // A

    val channelFactory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(clientBossPool, workerPool)
    val bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(channelFactory)

    // hangs waiting for shutdown latch in AbstractNioSelector (NioWorker or NioClientBoss
    // depending on the order of statement A, B, C) for
    // LinkedBlockingQueue, corePoolSize = 1 and sequence of statements A, B and C other than [B, A, C]
    // LinkedBlockingQueue, corePoolSize = 2 and sequence of statements A, B and C other than
    // [A, B, C], [B, C, A] and [C, B, A]
    bootstrap.shutdown()
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the executor service configuration has to meet some specific requirements, but which (core pool size, queue type)? bootstrap.shutdown() will block forever, except when the execution order of statement A, B and C is exactly [B, A, C]. Increasing core pool size to 2 blocks for three out of six combinations of the three statements. With a core pool size > 2 or with a SynchronousQueue each combination terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this seems like a bug. I think it works if xou use different executor for boss and workerpool. Can you open a bugreport ?

Comment: Ha! OK. I'll create a new issue against 3.6.3.